# .NET 7 ConfigurationBinder incorrect return type?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

In .NET 6, the `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>` method [used to return a `T`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-configuration-configurationbinder-get-1(microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfiguration)). In .NET 7, it's [now returning a `T?`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/63511baf6ca9c42bb65299e9233592bbfe7d4a3d/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L51). However, when I look at its source code, I don't see why it needs to be so:

```cs
public static T? Get<[DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.All)] T>(this IConfiguration configuration, Action<BinderOptions>? configureOptions)
{
    ThrowHelper.ThrowIfNull(configuration);

    object? result = configuration.Get(typeof(T), configureOptions);
    if (result == null)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    return (T)result;
}
```

Doesn't this function always actually return `T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return default(T);` will result in `null` if `T` is reference type or nullable value type (as shown in the [docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-operator) or you can check it out [yourself](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKzATgAo4BTAMwEMIAbYYgYQEoACAXndajtuYG48BEuWp0GASyjAA/G07deAvEIDMrDK0asA3nlYGN61ABZWAWWJs9uQ6wC+ee0A)), so the return type is correct.